# How to display text if one of the listview is empty out of multiple listViews in android fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have two `listview`s in my `Fragment`. At the beginning, the first top `listView` is empty because user didn't add any item in it. And after that there's another `listView` that has item already present in it. So I want to display a simple `textView` in place of that first `listView` if that first list is empty. For this, I used :

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
TextView emptyText = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
list.setEmptyView(emptyText);
```

But its not working. Here's my layout file below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables,MangledCRLF,ContentDescription,DisableBaselineAlignment,InefficientWeight,HardcodedText,UselessParent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="calibri-1361502412.ttf"
            android:text="My Companies"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#E5E5E5"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/t2"
            android:divider="#d0d0d0"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
        </ListView>

     <TextView 
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="You do not have any favorite company"/>  
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/listView1"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="calibri-1361502412.ttf"
            android:text="Industries  +"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#E5E5E5"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/t8"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/t1"
            android:divider="#d0d0d0"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/t7"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Its displaying text of that empty `textview` at top even if there is item in `list` or not. Please let me know how to do this..!!!

Comment: If there is no item in list, just set the visibility of `ListView` as `list.setVisibility(Visibility.GONE)` and set the text of `TextView`, `emptyText.setText("List is empty.")`.

Comment: tried this one too...but nothing happens...!!!

Comment: Are the other textviews visible? If the list is empty it does not occupy space i would say. So you don't have to do anything with the visibility of it i think. You have to set the visibility of the textview instead to GONE if the list gets content.

Comment: `list.setEmptyView(emptyText);`. Remove that from your code as it is useless and causes problems. You have that textview already in your layout xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the visibility as *T-rush* said and try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables,MangledCRLF,ContentDescription,DisableBaselineAlignment,InefficientWeight,HardcodedText,UselessParent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#E5E5E5"
            android:fontFamily="calibri-1361502412.ttf"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:text="My Companies"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/t7"
            android:layout_below="@+id/t2"
            android:divider="#d0d0d0"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:visibility="visible" >
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="You do not have any favorite company" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/t8"
            android:background="#E5E5E5"
            android:fontFamily="calibri-1361502412.ttf"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:text="Industries  +"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/t1"
            android:divider="#d0d0d0"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/t7"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```